# SuiteTalk SOAP API CustomFieldSearch in Java

Tags: soap, netsuite, suitetalk

I am using the Java proxies downloaded from http://content.netsuite.com/download/NSJavaClient2021-2.zip
Given a `CustomFieldRef` (with say, InternalId "30"), how do I fetch the name of this CustomField? In short, is there a CustomFieldSearch to search all CustomFields?

Answer (score 0):

In the soap world, you'll want to think of the `CustomField` as the superclass for a number of specialized classes like `TransactionBodyCustomField` or `EntityCustomField`.  From there, you can access the record using a standard `get` call.  I'm not familiar with the java-proxies, but in python, we'd do something like:

```
f = soap.get('transactionBodyCustomField', '30')
```

which would send an xml body with the appropriate recordRef xml.